# Generic error:class is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

Can someone explain to me why the following code does not work?

```
public class TestGeneric {

    EntityManager entityManager = new EntityManager();

    public <T extends Textable & Entity> void doAction(T obj) {
        entityManager.getAliasForEntityClass(obj.getClass());
    }
}

class EntityManager {

    public String getAliasForEntityClass(Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
        return clazz.getCanonicalName();
    }
}

interface Entity {
    Long getId();
}

interface Textable {
    String getText();
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
The method getAliasForEntityClass(Class<? extends Entity>) in the type EntityManager is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Class<capture#1-of ? extends Textable>)
```

If I wrote in this way, I did not have any error:

```
public class TestGeneric {

    EntityManager entityManager = new EntityManager();

    public <T extends Entity & Textable> void doAction(T obj) {
        entityManager.getAliasForEntityClass(obj.getClass());
    }
}

class EntityManager {

    public String getAliasForEntityClass(Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
        return clazz.getCanonicalName();
    }
}

interface Entity {
    Long getId();
}

interface Textable {
    String getText();
}
```

Template `<T extends Entity & Textable>` and `<T extends Textable & Entity>` means: T must implements Entity and Textable interfaces. Why position of interface so important in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the erasure of `T` is the leftmost type in the bound. From the `getClass()` documentation:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is
>   called.

The JLS specifies that "the erasure of a type variable is the erasure of its leftmost bound" (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)). So the type of `obj.getClass()` is `Class<? extends Textable>` in the first case and `Class<? extends Entity>` in the other.